# Select last row that is the same to others

Tags: mysql, select

Can you please help me to select the last row which is the same as others below?

Table looks as follow:

```
ID | NAME | VALUE | DATE |
1  | test | 1     | 2018 |
2  | test | 1     | 2018 |
14 | test | 0     | 2018 |
5  | test | 0     | 2018 |
7  | test | 0     | 2018 |
8  | test | 0     | 2018 |
9  | test | 0     | 2018 |
10 | test | 0     | 2018 |
```

But I want to select all the values with 1 and the first value as 0
So the result should looks like:

```
 ID | NAME | VALUE | DATE |
 1  | test | 1     | 2018 |
 2  | test | 1     | 2018 |
 14 | test | 0     | 2018 |
```

Comment: When you say 'First' you will need to specify an order, what order are the results in that you have posted?

Answer (score 0):

Use UNION ALL to combine record with value =1 and last record with value = 0. LIMIT 1 will only show the last record.

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE `value` = 1
UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT * 
      FROM yourTable
      WHERE `value` = 0
ORDER BY ID DESC
LIMIT 1) tab
```

Comment: Thanks :) Works as a charm.